# VBA to VB.NET excel filesave issue

Tags: vb.net, vba

I need to port a VBA app to VB.NET, there is only one problem excel won't save my template.

Excel opens the right file and it shows me the save file dialog, only one problem it won't save any file, however it won't give me an error but won't return me the file path because it doesn't save the file anywhere.

```
Filepath = Xl.GetSaveAsFilename("", "Excel file (*.xls), *.xls", , "titel")
    GeluidschermUserform.Excelfilenaam.Text = Filepath
```

Comment: GetSaveAsFileName doesn't save the file: it just asks the user to select a path and file name.  It's up to you to perform the save operation in your code.

Comment: ok so i need to use xl.savefile ?

Comment: Yes.  That should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Xl.SaveAs Filepath
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```